# Restricting variables to a domain in z3

Tags: z3py

Restricting BitVec's to the values of a list doesn't work as I expected, at least not by using `in`.

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

lst = [7, 11, 13, 14, 19, 21, 22, 25, 26, 28, 35, 37, 38, 41, 42, 44, 49, 50]
BV  = [BitVec(f"bv1{j + 1}", 8) for j in range(11)]
lst_as_domain = [bv in lst for bv in BV]
s.add(lst_as_domain)

print(lst_as_domain) #[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False]

print(s.check()) #unsat
```

If I use list comprehension as follows, it works.

```
from z3 import *

s = Solver()

lst = [7, 11, 13, 14, 19, 21, 22, 25, 26, 28, 35, 37, 38, 41, 42, 44, 49, 50]
BV  = [BitVec(f"bv{j + 1}", 8) for j in range(11)]

lst_as_domain = [Or([B[k] == li for li in lst]) for k in range(11)]

s.add(lst_as_domain)

print(lst_as_domain) #[Or(bv1 == 7, bv1 == 11,... ,bv1 == 50), Or(bv2 == 7,...)..] 
print(s.check()) #sat
print(s.model()) #[bv4 = 42, bv7 = 37,..., bv11 = 41]
```

Why doesn't the first code yield my desired restriction? How can I use `in` to assert a domain to variables, or is there a short command to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python's built-in `in` method does not do what you think it should do on symbolic expressions. This is a problem of the very loosely-typed nature of the z3 python bindings: Instead of doing symbolic equality, it checks for object equality, and always get `False` as an answer which you found when you printed `lst_as_domain`.

The solution is what you already found. Do *not* use `in`. For reuse purposes, I'd define a function like:

```py
def member(x, es):
    return Or([x == e for e in es])
```

And then use it as:

```py
lst_as_domain = [member(bv, lst) for bv in BV]
```

which will do the right thing and is "close" enough to what you wanted to write in the first place.

This is a common gotcha for the Python bindings, unfortunately. While it tries to make symbolic z3 expressions look and behave like Python expressions themselves, it doesn't always work due to limitations in Python and the z3-Python API itself; which makes it error-prone to use unless you're very careful about what methods are overloaded to work on symbolic expressions and which are not.

*Aside*: Unfortunately there's no easy way to tell which constructs will work on symbolic values out-of-the-box. You have to study how they're implemented internally. Rule-of-thumb: Anything that Python doesn't allow you to overload, you cannot use on symbolic values. But that's not an easy test, admittedly.

Comment: Thanks so much alias for your valuable explanation!